Docker and ECR deployment problems with Apple Silicon M3
Overview
I recently switched from an Intel machine to an M3 chip and I've been having problems with my image creation and deployment to ECR ever since. I should say, if it's not obvious, that I don't have a ton of experience with Docker and ECR so please bear with me.
I have always used AWS CDK (Python) to create and deploy images to Lambda functions. To try to isolate the problem I am currently manually building and deploying from terminal but in either case I get this error (certain attributes redacted to keep it shorter).
failed commit on ref "manifest-latest@sha256:xxx": unexpected status from PUT request to https://xxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/xxx-us-west-2/manifests/email-delivery-latest: 400 Bad Request
Questions
I have been using CDK to do this for a couple years now with no issue updating existing images so it seems like it has to be due to some conflict introduced by the M3 Apple Silicon chip.
Is there something causing conflicts between shared layers? Is the image itself possibly corrupt or invalid prior to upload (seems unlikely since it works when I remove the image from ECR in this case).
What else should I be looking at? Are there logs I could look at that could provide more information (sorry, again, not very experienced here).
I made it this far but now I'm totally lost so appreciate any help. I feel like there has to be a solution simpler than going back to my old computer...
Thanks in advance
Steps Taken
I navigate to the directory that has my Python files and Dockerfile
Here is my Dockerfile
WORKDIR /var/task

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY logo.png .
COPY email_template.html .
COPY download_package.py .
COPY send_email.py .
COPY lambda_handler.py .

CMD ["lambda_handler.handler"]

Here is my sequence of commands
mba1513:email_delivery xxx$ docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 --no-cache --load --provenance=false -t email-delivery .

mba1513:email_delivery xxx$ docker tag email-delivery:latest xxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx-us-west-2:email-delivery-latest

mba1513:email_delivery xxx$ docker push xxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdk-hnb659fds-container-assets-xxx-us-west-2:email-delivery-latest

The push refers to repository [xxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdk-hnb659fds-container-assets-xxx-us-west-2]
f4da91763964: Pushed 
17c2ed5dffb9: Pushed 
25b4adb3bba6: Layer already exists 
ba0258f06c34: Pushed 
4f4fb700ef54: Layer already exists 
ac33f3a27fe8: Layer already exists 
b3f6d63f6d08: Pushed 
a27918c84e84: Pushed 
3f1e1c3f67e3: Layer already exists 
1d9437365719: Pushed 
92726b091045: Pushed 
883897a1054f: Layer already exists 
551ede2dc115: Layer already exists 
35e8cd243a50: Layer already exists 
failed commit on ref "manifest-latest@sha256:xxx": unexpected status from PUT request to https://xxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/cdk-hnb659fds-container-assets-xxx-us-west-2/manifests/email-delivery-latest: 400 Bad Request

I was able to get this to deploy ok but I removed all but one package from the requirements.txt file (pandas) for testing. When I add another one, essentially changing the image I suppose, it breaks with the above error when I try to deploy. When I change it back to just `pandas` it still fails.
It seems like if I go into ECR and delete that container and try again it is more likely to deploy successfully on retry, even with all packages added back into requirements.txt.
Although it did work recently from a fresh deployment after deleting from ECR, I can't get the full stack to deploy from `cdk deploy` even when starting totally fresh (as far as I can tell), including having run `docker system prune -a`.
I have installed Rosetta, Docker is set to use Apple Visualization Framework, "use Rosetta" checkbox is checked, VirtioFS is selected.
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 --no-cache --load --provenance=false -t email-delivery .
[+] Building 16.0s (15/15) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                  docker-container:mybuilder
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 350B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.9s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [1/9] FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9@sha256:xxx                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => resolve public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9@sha256:xxx                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 259B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [2/9] WORKDIR /var/task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [3/9] COPY requirements.txt .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [4/9] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                                              9.7s
 => [5/9] COPY logo.png .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 => [6/9] COPY email_template.html .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => [7/9] COPY download_package.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => [8/9] COPY send_email.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [9/9] COPY lambda_handler.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => exporting to oci image format                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          5.2s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    3.4s
 => => exporting manifest sha256:xxx                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => exporting config sha256:xxx                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => sending tarball                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1.8s
 => importing to docker                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/mybuilder/mybuilder0/q353csyneq8orxxto53m0mmnp

mba1513:email_delivery xxx$ docker tag email-delivery:latest xxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdk-hnb659fds-container-assets-xxx-us-west-2:email-delivery-latest


I think I figured it out. It seems to work after a few updates:

set ecr repository "tag immutability" to "mutable"
added arg to DockerImageCode.from_image_asset() to set platform to amd64 (platform=ecr_assets.Platform.LINUX_AMD64)
prefixed cdk deploy command with BUILDX_NO_DEFAULT_ATTESTATIONS=1 as a way to get cdk to build the image to build with --provenance=false (BUILDX_NO_DEFAULT_ATTESTATIONS=1 cdk deploy)


Setting the repository to mutable is not required.
